# What is the IE10 'dominant color' picker based on?

Tags: colors, windows-8-preview, internet-explorer-10

I'm a web developer and I've just finished making a webapp that works almost flawlessly on all major browsers - except IE. IE has one teensy flaw: in IE10 Metro, when I pin the site to the start screen, it is peach instead of gray.

The IE team has said that this tile is based on the favicon's dominant color.

I've changed the favicon, and it seems that IE10 does **not** use the dominant color - peach, in my favicon, is a very small bit in a huge sea of gray (yes, one consistent color of gray.)

Instead, IE uses something else. I have no idea what it does use - the pixel at 10*10? the pixel at 15*15? but I'd be appreciative if someone knew and / or could figure it out.

So: What is the IE10 'dominant color' picker based on?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7 apps that are pinned to the taskbar, white and black are excluded from the executable's icon when determining the "glow" colour used when you wave your mouse over it. I wouldn't be surprised if they used the same logic in this context. If you made your favicon nothing but a block of grey, and still didn't see grey chosen, this would suggest I am right.

If you can't have grey, make some other colour more dominant than the peach and see if you can stand that.

Comment: Hmm. I'll try this and see what happens.